# AddField Method of PivotTable Class failed on macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a macro for automated process of creating a PivotChart based on an access table exported into excel format. However everytime when i attempt to insert two page fields into the PivotTable from the macro,i always get this error:

> Run-Time error '1004'
>
> AddFields Method Of PivotTable class failed

And the line it always shows to be the cause is this line of code

```
pt.AddFields RowFields:="RecordMonth", ColumnFields:="Department", PageFields:=Array("FiscalYear", "Department")
```

For reference,this is my code for the pivottable generation macro

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePivotTable()

Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable



Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheet1.Name & "!" & Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Set ws = Worksheets.Add
ws.Name = "MonthlyCalcTableTest"
Range("A3").Select

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ActiveCell, TableName:="AutoGenTest")

pt.AddFields RowFields:="RecordMonth", ColumnFields:="Department", PageFields:=Array("FiscalYear", "Department")


pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("MonthlyDepartmentBudget"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("ConfirmedValue"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum


pt.DataFields(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0"


End Sub
```

And these are the table column names in excel:

> ID, Department, MonthlyDepartmentBudget, FiscalYear, RecordMonth, Confirmation, AttachmentConfirmation, ConfirmedValue

AttachmentConfirmation is an attachment datatype and confirmation is true/false datatype

I would like to have some insight of why i was getting this error

Comment: "Department" is both a Column field and a Page field ?

Comment: I wanted to filter both by fiscal year and department in the tables and chart after auto generation

Comment: You can't manually add the same field to both "Columns" and "Filters" in a pivot table, so maybe that's a limitation here?

Comment: If I add a Field to "Columns" and then drag it (from the fields list) to "Filters", it disappears from "Columns" and appears in "Filters"

Comment: Ah ok ,i see,thanks for clarifying ,i guess my memory is from selecting the chart generation from the excel ribbon than vba macro creation

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the same field ("Department") to both `ColumnFields` and `PageFields`.